# 2002 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, wamp, port

My Website is deployed on a server with windows xp I am using WAMP SERVER.

Two days ago I am receiving this error continuously!

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] Only
>   one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted.

well I am newbie to this configuration world. I don't know what is the problem but I am **ALMOST** sure that it not coding or database problem. 
Where is the problem ?? Remember in my JS Coding I am using 3 to 5 setTimeOut function which make request to server after every 5 or 10 or 15 seconds. This can be a problem??

Please don't provide link I have checked already.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to start Apache twice, or you have 2 Apache's installed and one is being started automatically and therefore capturing port 80 before you manually start WAMPServer. **Whats changed on the PC running WAMPServer**